# Limit results from database using ajax (by selecting a dropdown menu)

Tags: php, ajax

So I got a simple dropdown menu with some values in it. What I want to happen is the following:

When a user selects a value in the dropdownlist, for example '8'. I want the query to change it's limit to 8.

And when a user selects '12' I want the limit to change to 12.

So change the amount of results loaded according to the value selected in the drop-down list.

I know I can achieve this with ajax, but I have no idea where to start. Does anyone know some good tutorials? Or does anyone have some code to get me started?

I'm familiar with PHP, just not with ajax.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly All tutorials are using old methods, I can't find any good turorials that use current code, such as mysqli or pdo.

Comment: They, that is _MYSQLI and PDO_ are just different method to achieve the same result. What I believe you are actually saying is you cannot find a bit of code you can _copy/paste_

Comment: @RiggsFolly No I can't find any tutorials not using deprecrated methods. Most tutorials I find are from 2014 or older.

Comment: @twan I don't understand why the issue is tutorials for MySQL when you're clearly asking a question about AJAX. MySQL is not even in your tags

Comment: @twan To clarify, SQL and Ajax (form submissions without forms ..) are completely separate from eachother, even if you use them in the same feature you are building.  Neither one requires or even needs to consider the other.  You are essentially creating two separate interfaces, so set up your querying as you normally do, and just use jquery to run your Ajax requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply what you can do:

```
$.get(
     'example.php',
     { limit: limit},
     function(data){
          ....
     }
);
```

Now from your php you can access to limit:

```
$limit = $_GET['limit'];
```

and then create your own query :
$sql = "SELECT ...... LIMIT $limit";

Comment: Great thanks. But how do I use this with a dropdown box? For example I pick 12, and limit gets 12 as a value?

Comment: Just take the value of dropdown box on submit. $('#id').val();

Answer (score 1):

AJAX in general is a pretty large conversation. To point you in the right direction though, AJAX is basically a workaround in javascript to allow php to execute on the server asynchronously with your JS code without the page refreshing. Just always remember that you have to have a callback for it to work properly. (That still hangs me up sometimes when I forget.) There are a lot of ways to do it. I would highly recommend the AJAX jQuery methods as they have a pretty shallow learniing curve and work well. Also,

Here is a link to a the jQuery explanation:
[AJAX jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)

Also, I would highly recommend using JSON as your data return format as it is quite a bit more powerful and simpler than XML.